# Node.js class recursive emission

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer

So, I'm trying the Ticker, Event Emitter Exercises from Hands On Node.js

I have this code:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter,
    util = require('util');

// Ticker Constructor
var Ticker = function (interval) {
    this.interval = interval;
    this.pulse = null;
}

util.inherits(Ticker, EventEmitter);

Ticker.prototype.start = function() {
    this.emit('start');
    this.tick();
}

Ticker.prototype.stop = function() {
    if (this.pulse != null) clearTimeout(this.pulse);
    this.emit('stop');
}

Ticker.prototype.tick = function() {
    this.emit('tick');
    this.pulse = setTimeout(this.tick, this.interval);
}

var ticker = new Ticker(1000);
ticker.on('start', function() { console.log('Ticker: Start'); });
ticker.on('tick', function() { console.log('Ticker: Tick'); });
ticker.on('stop', function() { console.log('Ticker: Stop'); });

ticker.start();
```

Which outputs the following, when run:

Ticker: Start
Ticker: Tick

```
timers.js:103
            if (!process.listeners('uncaughtException').length) throw e;
                                                                      ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'emit'
    at Object.Ticker.tick [as _onTimeout] (/Users/twilson/Projects/tutorials/node/ticker-01.js:23:8)
    at Timer.list.ontimeout (timers.js:101:19)
```

Where line `ticker-01.js:23` is `this.emit('tick');` of the `Ticker.prototype.tick` function.

Help, as I really can't see what on earth is going wrong, bound to be a scoping thing no doubt? :(

Comment: I don't have much experience with node, but did you try `this.tick.bind(this)` in the `setTimeout` call? That should take care of binding the instance.

Comment: Ticker isn't a module, it's a class I'm creating myself. :P

Comment: I just proved my inexperience there :)

Comment: Did you check what object 'this' refers to? I am thinking that @pimvdb is on the right track.

Comment: lol, I proved mine too with the question.  If you put it as an answer, I'll accept it for you kudos! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling `setTimeout(this.tick, this.interval)` the `tick` method will execute within the default context, not what `this` refers to right there.  You need to either...

Bind the value of `this` to the ticker instance:

```
setTimeout(this.tick.bind(this), this.interval)
```

Or save a reference to the ticker instance:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    self.tick();
}, this.interval);
```

Comment: "Saving the reference" is deemed dirty isn't it and something that Node.js aims to eradicate the need for, or did I mis-read something?

Comment: I use this approach all the time.  So does Node core: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L182

Comment: Perhaps you're remembering reading about CoffeeScript's fat arrow (=>)...it aims to alleviate this situation.

Comment: That is exactly correct scttnlsn. As I was also reading some CoffeeScript stuff today :P